# std::random_deviceが生成する数値列が毎回同じなのはOK？

Tags: c++, c++11, random

MinGW版GCCでは、`std::random_device`のデフォルトコンストラクターを使うと毎回同じ数値列が生成されますが、これは規格に準拠した動作なのでしょうか？
[実装の制限によって擬似乱数生成器を使うことは許されている](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/random/random_device.html)ようですが、`std::random_device`を使うということは予測不可能な乱数列を期待しているはずなので、種を固定して毎回同じ数値列が生成される（＝簡単に予測可能）のは、さすがにまずいと思うのですが。

参考：

- [gccをwindowsで使うならstd::random_deviceを使ってはいけない - Qiita](http://qiita.com/nanashi/items/f94b78398a6c79d939e1)

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rnd_gen;
    std::cout << rnd_gen() << "\n";
}
```

```
D:\home\tmp\random>g++ --version
g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0
…

D:\home\tmp\random>g++ -Wall -std=c++11 test_random_device.cpp

D:\home\tmp\random>a.exe
3499211612

D:\home\tmp\random>a.exe
3499211612

D:\home\tmp\random>a.exe
3499211612
```

Answer (score 2):

> 種を固定して毎回同じ数値列が生成される（＝簡単に予測可能）のは、さすがにまずいと思うのですが。

望ましい振る舞いではありませんが、ぎりぎりC++規格準拠といえる気はします。つまり "implementation-defined" の範囲内であり、単に実装の品質が著しく低いという解釈です。（それを不具合と呼ぶかどうかはもはや基準による？）

別の観点ですが、該当環境で `std::random_device{}.entropy() == 0.0` となっているか確認してみてください。処理系の都合で非決定的な乱数列を返せないときは、`entropy()`がゼロを返す仕様になっています。

関連する C++11仕様 §26.5.6 [rand.device] より引用（強調部分は回答者による）：

> 1 A `random_device` uniform random number generator produces non-deterministic random numbers.
>   2 If implementation limitations prevent generating non-deterministic random numbers, **the implementation may employ a random number engine.**
>
> `explicit random_device(const string& token = implementation-defined);`
>   3 *Effects:* Constructs a `random_device` non-deterministic uniform random number generator object. **The semantics and default value of the token parameter are implementation-defined.**
>
> `double entropy() const noexcept;`
>   5 *Returns:* If the implementation employs a random number engine, returns 0.0. Otherwise, returns an entropy estimate for the random numbers returned by `operator()`, in the range `min()` to log<sub>2</sub>(`max() + 1`).

---

追記：「種を固定して」と表現されていますが、`random_device`コンストラクタに与えるのは乱数生成エンジンに対する種(seed)ではなく、処理系に与えるトークン(token)です。本来の意図としては、いくつかの選択肢から乱数生成エンジンを"選ぶ"ためのものです。

Comment: MinGW版GCCでは、`entropy()`が0.0を返します。しかし、[同様に0.0を返す環境](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/random/random_device/entropy.html)でも、毎回異なる乱数列を返す環境（Cygwin版GCCなど）もあります。どうも`entropy()`は非決定的な乱数生成エンジンを使っているはずの環境でも0.0を固定で返す実装になっていて、この値は実質ほとんど意味がないような状況ですね。例：Red Hat版GCC→https://goo.gl/kG4pN6

Comment: 『追記：「種を固定して…』は承知していますが、GCCでは擬似乱数生成器を使う場合は種として使っています。しかも、指定しなければ種は固定になります。

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67578 たしかに`entropy()`は現状あてにならなそうですね。2個目コメントについては、tokenをPRNGのseedとして使うのもimplementation-definedの範疇かと思います。

Answer (score 2):

GCCの持つ`std::random_device`の主な実体ですが、

- [gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/random.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/846deaf01bfe46e0db44402858ab1b7ee43f4023/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.h#L1560-L1636)
- [gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/random.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/01e91138b88a77434927fca9485e28881f52a6a0/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/random.cc)

にあります。プリプロセッサマクロでコンパイル時に動作を分岐しています。

1. [`_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/866da453afff631a9c4a38ab18cfc1b1e719eb22/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/acinclude.m4#L2083-L2110)
   `/dev/random`か`/dev/urandom`かのどちらかのデバイスファイルが存在すれば`<random>`はTR1対応とする。ただしMinGW環境では誤検出するため常にTR1未対応とする。
2. [`_GLIBCXX_X86_RDRAND`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/866da453afff631a9c4a38ab18cfc1b1e719eb22/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/acinclude.m4#L3966-L3984)
   x86アーキテクチャの持つ[`RDRAND`命令](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand)が使用可能かテストする。

の２つが影響しています。その上で実際の動作としては

- ライブラリコンパイル時に`_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1`が定義され
- アプリケーションコンパイル時に`std::random_device`コンストラクター引数に`"default"`が渡され
- ライブラリコンパイル時に`_GLIBCXX_X86_RDRAND`が定義され
- アプリケーション実行時にCPUが`RDRAND`命令をサポートしているかテストし

すべての条件を満たした場合には`/dev/random`も`/dev/urandom`も使用せず`RDRAND`命令を使用する実装になっていました。

個人的にな感想としては、`RDRAND`を使用する優先順位が間違っている気がします。なおアプリケーションコンパイル時に無理やり`_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1`を定義しても必要なライブラリ関数が用意できていないためコンパイルには成功してもリンクエラーになるものと思われます。

---

説明に終始していて質問に答えていませんでした。

> MinGW版GCCでは、std::random_deviceのデフォルトコンストラクターを使うと毎回同じ数値列が生成されますが、これは規格に準拠した動作なのでしょうか？

[bits/random.h L1568～L1587](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/846deaf01bfe46e0db44402858ab1b7ee43f4023/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/random.h#L1568-L1587)を引用します。

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1

    explicit
    random_device(const std::string& __token = "default")
    {
      _M_init(__token);
    }

    ~random_device()
    { _M_fini(); }

#else

    explicit
    random_device(const std::string& __token = "mt19937")
    { _M_init_pretr1(__token); }

  public:

#endif
```

GCCとしては`_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1`が定義される環境（すなわち`/dev/random`か`/dev/urandom`かのどちらかのデバイスファイルを持ち、MinGW以外の環境）は`random_device::_M_init()`なのに対し、定義されない環境では`random_device::_M_init_pretr1()`という関数名を採用していることから読み取れるように**Pre TR1**、すなわちTR1以前という意識のようです。C++11どころの話ではなさそうです。

Comment: [`_GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/a2da7d8a13d5f044f056403a4a0656946753a54e/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/config.h.in#L948-L950)は、`/dev/random`と`/dev/urandom`が利用可能か否かを表しているようです。また、[libstdc++のClass random_deviceのstatus](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html)は、TR1もC++11もYになっています。ただし、[`include/c++/tr1/random.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/846deaf01bfe46e0db44402858ab1b7ee43f4023/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/tr1/random.h#L1461-L1544)を見ると、`! _GLIBCXX_USE_RANDOM_TR1`の方はTR1の時代から変わっていないので、取り敢えず作って忘れ去られてるのかも。